# Accumulate Every Other Element in a Vector C++

Tags: c++, accumulate

I want to be able to accumulate every other pair of elements in a vector using accumulate. I tried the following without much success, returning an error for a non-empty, non-zero vector

```
return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0,
      [&](int runningSum, int first, int second)
      {return runningSum = runningSum + min(first, second);});
```

which I now realise probably wouldn't be getting the minimum between pairs. For instance, if I have

```
vector<int> vec = {1,4,2,3}
```

I want to return 0 + min(1, 4) + min(2, 3).

On another note, is there any website with many examples of these STL built-ins? I find the examples online far and few. I really want to see the power of accumulate, and get comfortable with it.

Comment: cplusplus.com, cppreference.com

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux cplusplus.com is generally considered to be a poor site to use, stick with cppreference.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) does not allow you to use a predicate with 3 parameters, only 2 parameters - the current running sum, and the current element to be added to that sum. The predicate is called for each individual element and is expected to return the updated sum.

If you want to sum the values in pairs, you can try something like this instead:

```
vector<int> vec = {1,4,2,3};
...
int *first = nullptr;
return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0,
    [&](int runningSum, int &value) {
        if (first) {
            runningSum += std::min(*first, value);
            first = nullptr;
        } else {
            first = &value;
        }
        return runningSum;
    }
);
```

A better solution would be to simply change your `vector` to hold a pair of `int`s (like [`std::pair<int, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)) as its element type (or at least copy your vector `int`s to a second `vector` of pairs), and then you can accumulate the pairs as-is:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vec = {{1,4},{2,3}};
...
return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0,
    [](int runningSum, const pair<int, int> &p) {
        return runningSum + std::min(p.first, p.second);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be difficult to just use accumulate straight away to sum by min of pairs. You would need to maybe split your existing vector first, then transform them into a vector of the mins, then you could use the accumulate function.

So with that in mind, I would maybe do it like this:

```
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,4,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v2;
    std::vector<int> v3;
    std::vector<int> v4;

    std::partition_copy(begin(v),
                        end(v),
                        back_inserter(v2),
                        back_inserter(v3),
                        [toggle = false](int) mutable { return toggle = !toggle; });

    std::transform(begin(v2), end(v2), begin(v3), std::back_inserter(v4), [](auto a, auto b)
    {
        return std::min(a,b);
    });

    auto sum_of_min_in_pairs =  std::accumulate(begin(v4), end(v4), 0);
```

Note that the code above will have issues if your vector does not have even amount of elements. Otherwise, transform it into a pair, with some default to match the remainder, depending on what you want to achieve.

With the STL website, cppreference.com is your friend. There are also a few books around I would highly recommend.

- Effective STL by Scott Meyers
- The C++ standard library by Nicolai Josuttis

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using `std::adjacent_difference` and `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::min
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>   // std::adjacent_difference, std::accumulate
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector v{1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8, 5, 1};
  std::adjacent_difference(
      v.cbegin(), v.cend(), v.begin(),
      [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return std::min(lhs, rhs); });
  auto is_second_elem{true};
  std::cout << std::accumulate(cbegin(v), cend(v), 0,
                               [&is_second_elem](auto acc, auto min) {
                                 is_second_elem = not is_second_elem;
                                 return is_second_elem ? (acc + min) : acc;
                               })
            << '\n'; // 7
}
```